# Magento 2: Need to check function for auto stock status changed

Tags: magento2.4, manage-stock

I have configurable products and its child items in Magento 2.4 admin panel
I have 3 child items for one configurable parent. If I set out of stock for 2 items and save then parent would be in in stock. If I save child items with out of stock then when I check status of parent stock status it automatically stock to out of stock because all child items are out of stock so parent automatically become out of stock so I need to check the which function doing this stuff ?

I looked at into files `save()` function is the responsible into below file location to doing above stuff ?

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository.php
```

Comment: can you specify what actual you are looking?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I want to put my custom code over there so I am finding that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has observer named SaveInventoryDataObserver under `vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver.php`

In execute function of this observer, it triggers  `$this->processParents($product);`
which process stock data for parent products.

```
private function processParents(Product $product)
{
    foreach ($this->parentItemProcessorPool as $processor) {
        $processor->process($product);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `magento-configurable-product/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\SaveInventoryDataObserver">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="parentItemProcessorPool" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="configurable" xsi:type="object"> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Inventory\ParentItemProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
</type>
```

this will further hit the `magento-configurable-product/Model/Inventory/ParentItemProcessor.php`

This class has below function `processStockForParent` which might be responsible for this(**parent stock status it automatically stock to out of stock**).

```
private function processStockForParent(int $productId)
    {
        $criteria = $this->criteriaInterfaceFactory->create();
        $criteria->setScopeFilter($this->stockConfiguration->getDefaultScopeId());

        $criteria->setProductsFilter($productId);
        $stockItemCollection = $this->stockItemRepository->getList($criteria);
        $allItems = $stockItemCollection->getItems();
        if (empty($allItems)) {
            return;
        }
        $parentStockItem = array_shift($allItems);

        $childrenIds = $this->configurableType->getChildrenIds($productId);
        $criteria->setProductsFilter($childrenIds);
        $stockItemCollection = $this->stockItemRepository->getList($criteria);
        $allItems = $stockItemCollection->getItems();

        $childrenIsInStock = false;

        foreach ($allItems as $childItem) {
            if ($childItem->getIsInStock() === true) {
                $childrenIsInStock = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($this->isNeedToUpdateParent($parentStockItem, $childrenIsInStock)) {
            $parentStockItem->setIsInStock($childrenIsInStock);
            $parentStockItem->setStockStatusChangedAuto(1);
            $this->stockItemRepository->save($parentStockItem);
        }
    }
```

For more information refer this commit -
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/a52d069900777c291d27b2e20c122970b7aaecca